# Custom Maven Settings/Build Locations per Intellij maven module

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Is it possible to have custom maven settings/build Locations per Intellij maven module?

It seems that these maven settings belong to workspace.xml which is provided per project but not per module. I need the same code fragment given in workspace.xml:

```xml
  <component name="MavenImportPreferences">
    <option name="generalSettings">
      <MavenGeneralSettings>
        <option name="mavenHome" value="<CUSTOM>" />
        <option name="userSettingsFile" value="<CUSTOM>" />
      </MavenGeneralSettings>
    </option>
    <option name="importingSettings">
      <MavenImportingSettings>
        <option name="importAutomatically" value="true" />
      </MavenImportingSettings>
    </option>
  </component>
```

for each .iml, or is there any custom workspace.xml available for modules?

Comment: Why do you want different `settings.xml` for different Maven modules or projects?

Comment: Because one module is a jira plugin with custom (modded) maven and settings.xml and the rest should use the standard maven.

Comment: For instance, this is a usual configuration in eclipse. You can setup custom maven tools for each project.
I could do the same in intellij, but only one project is shown per window not so for modules, usually eclipse project == jetbrains module, so I need this setting for modules, too

Answer (score 0):

intellij maven developer online.

There is no way now to setup different maven distributions for different linked maven projects in settings now. (we are plannning to do this in future)

As a workaround you can try use maven wrapper. IDEA supports maven wrapper for each project now in 2020.1, however only for importing.  Execution via mvnw to be supported later.